# converting storm topology to flink - "no entry class specified"?

Tags: jar, apache-storm, apache-flink

I'm working through [these](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/storm_compatibility.html) directions to convert an existing storm topology into a flink job. I have flink 1.0 (SNAPSHOT) installed via git  and have the webserver and streaming server running locally.

I build the topology via gradle into a .jar file and submit it via the flink web interface and get this message: "no entry class specified".

So - missing an entry point? Something special needed for the .jar? A manifest?

This .jar was working when submitted to a storm cluster. I've added (what seem like) the relevant flink .jar files.

---

### Edit:

Submitting the job via the cmd-line showed me this message:

> org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Neither a 'Main-Class', nor a 'program-class' entry was found in the jar file.
>       at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.getEntryPointClassNameFromJar(PackagedProgram.java:563)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.(PackagedProgram.java:186)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.(PackagedProgram.java:124)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.buildProgram(CliFrontend.java:725)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:287)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:971)
>       at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1021)

Reading [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-1225) JIRA suggests some answers:

1. Add a manifest
2. Add the entry point on the cmd-line (use the '-c <package>' option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flink, there are two ways to specify the entry point class that contains the

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method. This applies to Storm topologies that are executed in Flink, too.

1. Include a manifest file in your `jar` (the corresponding entry must be either `Main-Class` or `program-class`, ie, "`program-class: package.and.EntryClass`")
2. You can specify the `-c` flag (ie, `bin/flink run -c package.and.EntryClass <jarFile.jar>` (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/cli.html)

If you are using Flink's WebClient, you can specify the `-c` flag in the input field *Flink Options* (see here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/web_client.html)